# PTR record only added on IP owner side? no in DNS Zone files?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone, ptr-record

i wanted to add PTR record, to my domain so the reverse IP is in PTR points to my nameserver.

So on my hosting IP provider i set my nameserver for the IP and it now shows in PTR (i used [this tutorial](http://internetlifeforum.com/general-server-webmaster-discussion/838-tutorial-how-setup-valid-ptr-check-if-exist/)),

but i want to ask, if **i need to setup PTR in my DNS domain zone file too**?

99.88.77.66.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR ns1.mydomainname.com.

there is no PTR, only A, NS, MX and similar

?

Answer (score 4):

PTR Records are only added in the in-addr.arpa. zones of the IP owner. But the A and PTR records should match. This means the PTR

```
99.88.77.66.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR ns1.mydomainname.com.
```

should have a matching A record in your mydomainname.com DNS zone:

```
ns1                       IN   A 66.77.88.99
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[~] dig +short ns 77.66.in-addr.arpa.
authns2.qwest.net.
authns1.qwest.net.
```

Is where the PTR record would need to be created, as that is where that `in-addr.arpa` zone has been delegated to. You will need to contact qwest (or perhaps NBC universal, who the /24 is delegated to from Qwest)  to request it.

You can ask if they can use RFC 2317 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2317.txt) in order to delegate the PTR to your name servers since it doesn't lay on an octet boundary. but for a single IP address, they probably wont.

Comment: I think this is an example IP address.

Comment: ahh Could be.  Just replace the ip with the correct one and trace the delegation to find out needs to be contacted.